# How do I get an HttpRequestMessage object from an HttpRequest object?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to use a library that expects an `HttpRequestMessage` object, but my Web API controller action only provides an `HttpRequest` object as `Request`.

Answer (score 0):

This little helper creates a proxy `HttpRequestMessage` from `HttpRequest`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static HttpRequestMessage GetHttpRequestMessage(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(request.GetEncodedUrl());
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        string requestMethod = request.Method;
        if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsHead(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsDelete(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsTrace(requestMethod))
        {
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(request.Body);
            requestMessage.Content = streamContent;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues> header in request.Headers)
        {
            if (!requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray()) && requestMessage.Content != null)
            {
                requestMessage.Content?.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
            }
        }

        requestMessage.Headers.Host = uri.Authority;
        requestMessage.RequestUri = uri;
        requestMessage.Method = new HttpMethod(request.Method);

        return requestMessage;
    }
}
```